# How do I read the value for and XML node and check if the value is correct

Tags: c#, xml, validation

I am fairly new to programming and need to check a Single node in a XML file for a certain value and need to check if that value is correct.

I need to validate these 3 Nodes in 3 different classes:

```
<RunCodeAnalysis>true</RunCodeAnalysis>
```

I need to select this specific node from a xml file and need to check if the value of the node is true, i hope to get some help with the validation if the value is acutally true

```
private void CodeAnalysisEnabled(XDocument xmlDoc)
{
    var codeAnalysis = from doc in xmlDoc.Root?.Descendants("RunCodeAnalysis") select doc;

    foreach (var codeAnalysisNode in codeAnalysis)
    {
        codeAnalysisNode.Value = "true";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - I would personally recommend using LINQ to XML, then you may well not even need to use `SelectSingleNode`, and it'll be easier to check the values etc. At the moment your question is too vague for us to help you, I'm afraid.

Comment: Please edit the *question* rather than just adding comments.

Comment: Well you still haven't shown any of the code you've got so far, or what counts as "valid"...

Answer (score 0):

Load XML and use XPath to search for tags:

```
var document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load(fileName);
var root = document.DocumentElement
var nodes = root.SelectNodes("//RunCodeAnalysis");
```

This sample selects all *RunCodeAnalysis* nodes from XML. Using XPath you can select exactly what you want. [Check this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I'd personally use LINQ to XML for that - `XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fileName); var nodes = root.Descendants("RunCodeAnalysis");`

Comment: @JonSkeet hey jon i got the selection to work and updated the problem now with code and what i need to do. could you have another look ?

Comment: @Pagodatree: No, because it's still not clear what you're trying to achieve. You're currently *modifying* all the values - and using LINQ for no obvious reason - I thought you were trying to *check* them?